# UITableViewRowAction - delay dismiss animation until confirmation

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

I googled over 2h and found nothing useful:
I have a tableView with editActions. When I press the action, I present an alertController with additional info/needed confirmation.

The editActions are dismissed right after the alertController is displayed.
I want to wait the dismiss animation until my alterController gets dismissed.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DocumentTableViewCell

        self.askUserForDeleteFile() { (shallDelete) in
            if shallDelete {
                self.imageDocumentHandler?.deleteDocumentOfDatabase(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
            }
        }
    }

    let deselect = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "kickout") { (action, indexPath) in
            self.folder?.removeFromDocuments(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
    }

    deselect.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 247/255, green: 162/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1.0)

    return [deselect,delete]
}

func askUserForDeleteFile(completion: @escaping (Bool)->()) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "delete document?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "delete", style: .destructive) { (_) in
        completion(true)
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in
        completion(false)
    }

    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the standard behaviour of editAction swiping to delete. However If you are targeting IOS 11 or above then there is new method you can use to achieve what you need. You can do something like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let delete = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.destructive, title: "delete", handler: { (action, view, completion) in

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DocumentTableViewCell

        self.askUserForDeleteFile() { (shallDelete) in
            if shallDelete {
                self.imageDocumentHandler?.deleteDocumentOfDatabase(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
            }
            completion(true)
        }
    })

    let deselect = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.normal, title: "kickout", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
         self.folder?.removeFromDocuments(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
        completion(true)
    })

    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, deselect])
    return config
}
```

The completion will prevent the animation being dismissed until-unless specified. However if your target is IOS 10, you will still need the editAction method.

Comment: If the user clicks cancel, the row shall not be deleted. So the completion(true) for delete has to be inside the if shallDelete {} block.

`if shallDelete {
                    self.imageDocumentHandler?.deleteDocumentOfDatabase(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
                    completion(true)
                }
                else {
                    completion(false)
                }`

Comment: Can editActionsForRowsAt use completion? Or is that iOS 11+ only? I'd like to be able to leave the actions visible even when the table reloads. Reason - social app that may have an active channel getting multiple comments on a post. If a user wants to reply to a comment I'd like to leave these visible. Right now if a new comment comes in while a cell's actions are visible it dismisses and the user will have to swipe the cell again.